# Smart_listing locals params does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smart-listing

I'm rendering smart_listing partial view with locals parameters:

```
smart_listing_render(:user_ldaproles, locals: {ldapuser: @ldapuser})
```

The local parameter `ldapuser` works for the firt page, which is rendered.
But when i click on next page at at the smart_listing, the local parameter `ldapuser` is `nil`.

```
13:05:52 web.1     | Started GET "/ldapusers/kru0096?user_ldaproles_smart_listing%5Bpage%5D=2" for 10.0.1
13:27:09 web.1     |   Rendered ldapusers/show.js.erb (1946.1ms)
13:27:09 web.1     | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1980ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
13:27:09 web.1     | 
13:27:09 web.1     | 
13:27:09 web.1     | 
13:27:09 web.1     | NameError - undefined local variable or method `ldapuser' for #<#<Class:0x00007f4f6c
bb2638>:0x00007f4f6d4a5ab0>
13:27:09 web.1     | Did you mean?  @ldapuser:
13:27:09 web.1     |   app/views/ldapusers/_ldaproles.haml:24:in `block in _app_views_ldapusers__ldaprole
s_haml__4226213442704361194_69988992008260'
13:27:09 web.1     |   app/views/ldapusers/_ldaproles.haml:10:in `_app_views_ldapusers__ldaproles_haml__4
226213442704361194_69988992008260'
13:27:09 web.1     |   app/views/ldapusers/show.js.erb:2:in `_app_views_ldapusers_show_js_erb__8937577382
81268117_69989556369100'
```

I could use global parameter `@ldapuser` but gem `rails_best_practicies` does not like it.

How can I get local parameters, passed to `smart_listing_render`, to keep their value, when going to next page?

#### Edit:

`app/views/ldapusers/show.js.erb:`

```
<%= smart_listing_update :user_ldaproles %>
```

Comment: What does file _app/views/ldapusers/show.js.erb_ contain?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh file added to question

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I've noticed, that my `smart_listing_update` is wrong. I fixed it to proper name, and the error changed a little bit.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Oh god, I get it now. `show.js.erb` have to contain locals parameter like `<%= smart_listing_update :user_ldaproles, locals: {ldapuser: @ldapuser} %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the problem in my `app/views/ldapusers/show.js.erb` file.

The file has to update the locals' parameters as well.

```
<%= smart_listing_update :user_ldaproles, locals: {ldapuser: @ldapuser} %>
```

Then the pagination work.